# Why does the Rust compiler error with "cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable" after moving the variable into a scope?

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

After reading about Rust's scopes and references, I wrote a simple code to test them.

```rust
fn main() {
    // 1. define a string
    let mut a = String::from("great");

    // 2. get a mutable reference
    let b = &mut a;
    b.push_str(" breeze");
    println!("b = {:?}", b);

    // 3. A scope: c is useless after exiting this scope
    {
        let c = &a;
        println!("c = {:?}", c);
    }

    // 4. Use the mutable reference as the immutable reference's scope
    //    is no longer valid.
    println!("b = {:?}", b);  // <- why does this line cause an error?
}
```

As far as I understand:

- Immutables and mutables cannot be used simultaneously.
- 2 mutables of same object cannot exist.

  - But scoping can allow 2 mutable to exist as long as 2 mutables are not in
    the same scope.

#### Expectation

In `3`, `c` is created within a scope, and no mutables are used in it. Hence,
when `c` goes out of scope, it is clear that `c` will not be used anymore (as
it would be invalid) and hence `b`, a mutable reference, can be used safely in
`4`.

The expected output:

```
b = "great breeze"
c = "great breeze"
b = "great breeze"
```

#### Reality

Rust produces the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
6  |     let b = &mut a;
   |             ------ mutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |         let c = &a;
   |                 ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |     println!("b = {:?}", b); // <- why does this line cause an error?
   |                          - mutable borrow later used here
```

#### Inference

(This is just what I think is happening, and can be a fallacy)

It seems that no matter what, you cannot use any mutable references (`b`)
once an immutable reference (`c`) was made (or "seen" by the rust
compiler), whether in a scope or not.

This is much like:

> At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any
> number of immutable references.

This situation is similar to:

```rust
let mut a = String::from("great");

let b = &mut a;
b.push_str(" breeze");
println!("b = {:?}", b);
// ^ b's "session" ends here. Using 'b' below will violate the rule:
// "one mutable at a time"

// can use multiple immutables: follows the rule
// "Can have multiple immutables at one time"
let c = &a;
let d = &a;
println!("c = {:?}, d = {:?}", c, d);
println!("b = {:?}", b); // !!! Error
```

Also, as long as we are using immutable references, the original object
or reference becomes "immutable". As said in [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references):

> We *also* cannot have a mutable reference while we have an immutable one.
> Users of an immutable reference don’t expect the values to suddenly
> change out from under them!

and

> ...you can have either one mutable reference...

```rust
let mut a = String::from("great");

let b = &mut a;
b.push_str(" breeze");
println!("b = {:?}", b);

let c = &b; // b cannot be changed as long as c is in use
b.push_str(" summer"); // <- ERROR: as b has already been borrowed.
println!("c = {:?}", c); // <- immutable borrow is used here
```

So this code above somewhat explains @Shepmaster's solution.

Going back to the original code and removing the scope:

```rust
// 1. define a string
let mut a = String::from("great");

// 2. get a mutable reference
let b = &mut a;
b.push_str(" breeze");
println!("b = {:?}", b);

// 3. No scopes here.
let c = &a;
println!("c = {:?}", c);


// 4. Use the mutable reference as the immutable reference's scope
//    is no longer valid.
println!("b = {:?}", b);  // <- why does this line cause an error?
```

Now it is clear why this code has an error. The rust compiler sees that
we are using a mutable `b` (which is a mutable reference of `a`,
therefore `a` becomes immutable) while also borrowing an immutable
reference `c`. I like to call it "no immutables in between".

Or we can also call it "un-sandwiching". You cannot have/use a mutable
between "immutable declaration" and "immutable use" and vice-versa.

But this still does not answer the question of **why scopes fail here**.

#### Question

- Even after explicitly moving `c` into a scope, why does the Rust
  compiler produce this error message?

Comment: You've lost the "chain of custody"; `c` invalidates `b`. Instead, do `let c = &*b;`

Comment: @Shepmaster What exactly is a "chain of custody" in Rust? It is a new term for me, and I never saw it in the docs while reading about refs and scopes. Please keep the answer beginner friendly.

Comment: It's not a real term used by Rust.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is why doesn't compiler allow `c` to refer to data which is already mutably borrowed. I for one would expect that to be disallowed to begin with!

But - when you comment out the very last `println!()`, the code compiles correctly. Presumably that's what led you to conclude that aliasing is allowed, "as long as mutables aren't in the same scope". I argue that that conclusion is incorrect, and here is why.

While it's true that there are some cases where aliasing is allowed for references in sub-scopes, it requires further restrictions, such as narrowing an existing reference through struct projection. (E.g. given a `let r = &mut point`, you can write `let rx = &mut r.x`, i.e. temporarily mutably borrow a subset of mutably borrowed data.) But that's not the case here. Here `c` is a completely new shared reference to data already mutably referenced by `b`. That should never be allowed, and yet it compiles.

The answer lies with the compiler's analysis of [non-lexical lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html) (NLL). When you comment out the last `println!()`, the compiler notices that:

1. `b` isn't `Drop`, so no one can observe a difference if we pretend it was dropped sooner, perhaps immediately after last use.
2. `b` is no longer used after the first `println!()`.

So NLL inserts an invisible `drop(b)` after the first `println!()`, thereby allowing introduction of `c` in the first place. It's only because of the implicit `drop(b)` that `c` doesn't create a mutable alias. In other words, the scope of `b` is artificially shortened from what would be determined by purely *lexical* analysis (its position relative to `{` and `}`), hence *non-lexical* lifetime.

You can test this hypothesis by wrapping the reference in a newtype. For example, this is equivalent to your code, and it still compiles with the last `println!()` commented out:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Ref<'a>(&'a mut String);

fn main() {
    let mut a = String::from("great");

    let b = Ref(&mut a);
    b.0.push_str(" breeze");
    println!("b = {:?}", b);

    {
        let c = &a;
        println!("c = {:?}", c);
    }

    //println!("b = {:?}", b);
}
```

But, if we merely implement `Drop` for `Ref`, the code no longer compiles:

```
// causes compilation error for code above
impl Drop for Ref<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
    }
}
```

To explicitly answer your question:

> Even after explicitly moving `c` into a scope, why does the Rust compiler produce this error message?

Because `c` is not allowed to exist alongside `b` to begin with, regardless of being an an inner scope. When it *is* allowed to exist is in cases where the compiler can prove that `b` is never used in parallel with `c` and it's safe to drop it before `c` is even constructed. In that case aliasing is "allowed" because there's no actual aliasing despite `b` "being in scope" - on the level of the generated MIR/HIR, it's only `c` that refers to the data.